# Edit a TensorFlow checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know that there's a way to examine TF checkpoints (such as described in [inspect_checkpoint.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e0344f1e7ceff9c192369000d244c4ca47d7a1cc/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py)).

However, is there a way to update certain weights in this checkpoint and write it back, without having to construct the whole model? For example, I want to quickly edit the weights of one of the layers and write it back, and don't want to write the code for the deep network this model corresponds to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MetaGraph saving and loading](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html). There are a few examples there; you should be able to define the model, save the MetaGraph, then load and modify it without re-defining the variables manually.

Comment: Thanks! Though ideally I think it would be great to have a `CheckpointWriter` method (more discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/discuss/_U7C1T_-XsI)). Anyway this seems best solution as of now, so I'll accept it.