# How to load, edit, and then save a TensorFlow checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to be able to load in all weights and biases of a TensorFlow checkpoint, apply some mathematical operations to the weights and biases (such as thresholding, scaling, etc), and then save a new TensorFlow checkpoint with the same structure as the original but with the edited weights and biases. Using an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218174/how-to-find-the-variable-names-that-are-saved-in-a-tensorflow-checkpoint) I am able to successfully load a TensorFlow checkpoint and view the names and contents of the tensors within it, but I am unable to make changes to these tensors. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325245/edit-a-tensorflow-checkpoint) asks a similar question and the asker is referred to [this documentation on MetaGraphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph), but I am new to TensorFlow and so I don't see how this information could be helpful.

So, what is the most effective way to load, edit, and then save TensorFlow checkpoints?